# reactJS with a dynamic bootsrap menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a reactJS application and I need to dynamically build a bootstrap menu.  In the general render of my application, I have the following code:

```
<div className="container">
    <nav className="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
        <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">{this.state.planName}</a>
        <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        {this.renderMenu()}
   </nav>
</div>
```

This is the code that I have in my {this.renderMenu()}

```
return (
    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
            <li className="nav-item">
                <a className="nav-link" onClick={this.accountinformation}>Account Information</a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
                <a className="nav-link" onClick={this.investmentelections}>Investment Elections</a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
                <a className="nav-link" onClick={this.contributions}>Contributions</a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
                <a className="nav-link" onClick={this.beneficiary}>Beneficiariy Information</a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
                <a className="nav-link" onClick={this.transactionhistory}>Transaction History</a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
                <a className="nav-link" onClick={this.transfer}>Transfer</a>
            </li>
            <li class="active"><a href="/preventback">Logout</a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
   )
```

This all works perfectly well.  However, what I would like to do if only render the beneficiary menu option if menuBene = "Y", only render the transfer menu option if menuTransfer = "Y" and only render the  transaction history menu option if menuTransaction = "Y".

Is there a syntax that allows me to have a condition within the render?  Something like this:

```
return (
    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
            <li className="nav-item">
                <a className="nav-link" onClick={this.accountinformation}>Account Information</a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
                <a className="nav-link" onClick={this.investmentelections}>Investment Elections</a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
                <a className="nav-link" onClick={this.contributions}>Contributions</a>
            </li>
            if (menuBene == "Y") {
                <li className="nav-item">
                    <a className="nav-link" onClick={this.beneficiary}>Beneficiariy Information</a>
                </li>
             }
             if (menuTransaction == "Y") {
                <li className="nav-item">
                    <a className="nav-link" onClick={this.transactionhistory}>Transaction History</a>
                </li>
             }
             if (menuTransfer == "Y") {
                <li className="nav-item">
                    <a className="nav-link" onClick={this.transfer}>Transfer</a>
                </li>
             }
            <li class="active"><a href="/preventback">Logout</a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and concise way to do this is to use inline `if &&`syntax

https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you so much!